# MYSQL 3 table query; sum table B (if found) for each in table A; Use table C (if found) to sort results

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables (jobs, job_tasks, job_hours)

I want to get the SUM of the tasks for each job (if any) and order the results based on the most recent hours assigned to the job.  I'm getting all the jobs and it's ordering them correctly but I'm getting 12 for taskactive when it should be 1.  It appears that it keeps adding the same task for each day hours have toward that job.

```
select MAX(job_hours.job_date) as lastWorked, SUM(job_tasks.active) as taskactive, jobs.job_type
from jobs 
left outer join job_tasks on jobs.idjobs = job_tasks.idjobs
left outer join job_hours on jobs.idjobs = job_hours.idjob
where jobs.active = '1' and jobs.completed = '0'
group by jobs.idjobs 
ORDER BY  job_hours.job_date desc, jobs.job_created_date DESC
```

[results showing incorrect task count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdD15.png)

If I remove the job_hours I get the correct SUM(job_tasks.active) of 1

```
select SUM(job_tasks.active) as taskactive, jobs.job_type
from jobs 
left outer join job_tasks on jobs.idjobs = job_tasks.idjobs
where jobs.active = '1' and jobs.completed = '0'
group by jobs.idjobs 
ORDER BY jobs.job_created_date DESC
```

[Results showing correct task count](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54CWq.png)

Table jobs

```
 idjobs    job_type                                        active  completed      job_created_date  
  137    Installation, Other (Furnace 28 Rebuild )          1        0        2018-01-23 07:37:36  
  138    Preventive Maintenance (Monthly 2018-February )    1        1        2018-01-23 07:38:12  
  139    Preventive Maintenance (Monthly 2018-March )       1        0        2018-01-23 07:38:20
```

Table job_tasks

```
idjob_tasks    idjobs   active  task  
 68              137       1    "Serial Number Verification"
```

Table job_hours

```
idjob_hours    idjob    job_date    idemployee  
    190         137    2018-02-21       9  
    197         138    2018-02-21       3  
    198         138    2018-02-21       3  
    199         138    2018-02-20       3  
    201         138    2018-02-22       3  
    202         137    2018-02-19       9  
    203         137    2018-02-20       9  
    204         137    2018-03-08       9  
    205         137    2018-02-23       7  
    206         137    2018-02-19       7  
    207         137    2018-02-20       7  
    209         137    2018-02-22       9  
    216         137    2018-02-22       7  
    217         137    2018-02-21       7  
    218         137    2018-02-21       9  
    220         137    2018-02-23       9  
    255         139    2018-03-12       9  
    260         139    2018-03-13       9  
    261         139    2018-03-14       9
```

Comment: Sample data is helpful to us.

Comment: I added table data that gives me the 12 result when it should only be 1.

Comment: Probably duplicating rows in the second join. Is that the primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `job_hours` table in the join, use a subquery to generate a table from `job_hours` that will contain only the latest `job_date` grouped by `idjob`:

```
SELECT MAX(job_hours.job_date) as lastWorked, 
  SUM(job_tasks.active) as taskactive, 
  jobs.job_type 
FROM jobs 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN job_tasks ON jobs.idjobs = job_tasks.idjobs 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(job_date) as job_date, idjob 
    FROM job_hours 
    GROUP BY idjob) as job_hours ON job_hours.idjob = jobs.idjobs 
WHERE jobs.active = '1'  
  and jobs.completed = '0' 
GROUP BY jobs.idjobs 
ORDER BY jobs.job_created_date DESC;
```

This query will output:

```
+------------+------------+----------------------------------------------+
| lastWorked | taskactive | job_type                                     |
+------------+------------+----------------------------------------------+
| 2018-03-08 |          1 | Installation, Other (Furnace 28 Rebuild )    |
| 2018-03-14 |       NULL | Preventive Maintenance (Monthly 2018-March ) |
+------------+------------+----------------------------------------------+
```